# Finding position in a String

Tags: string, vba, excel

I want to find the position of a sub String in a String but facing some issues. Here is the code

```
Function findPos( Searchval As String, Output As String) As Long
Dim pos, i, count As Long
pos = InStr(1, content, searchVal, 0)

If pos = 0 Then
    count = 0
Else
    count = 1
End If

If pos > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To pos
        If Mid(content, i, 1) = "/" Then count = count + 1
    Next i
End If

findPos=count

End Function
```

For eg: If output is **"AA/AE_ABC/AE/CD"** and if I searchVal is **"AE"** then I get output position as 2 which is wrong as I should get 3. I know that **pos** in code has to be modified somehow but can't figure it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout As AE is positioned third in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to find the position of the string then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print findPos("AE", "AA/AE_ABC/AE/CD")
End Sub

Function findPos(Searchval As String, Output As String) As Long
    findPos = InStr(1, Output, Searchval, 0)
End Function
```

BTW, the position is `4` and not `3`

Edit: If you are looking for position after "/" then try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print findPos("AE", "AA/AE_ABC/AE/CD")
End Sub

Function findPos(Searchval As String, Output As String) As Long
    Dim MyAr
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Check if output has "/"
    If InStr(1, Output, "/", 0) Then
        '~~> Split it and store it in an array
        MyAr = Split(Output, "/")

        '~~> Loop through the array to find an exact match
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            If MyAr(i) = Searchval Then
                findPos = i + 1
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        '~~> Check if both Searchval and Output are same
        If Output = Searchval Then findPos = 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean that AA 0,/ 1, AE_ABC 2,/ 3 , AE 4 ?

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to achieve. Check my answer. I have edited that. You may have to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you, commented for clarity:

```
Function findPos(ByVal strFind As String, _
                 ByVal strContent As String, _
                 Optional ByVal sDelimiter As String = "/") As Long

    'strFind is the substring you're searching for
    'strContent is the string you're looking in for strFind
    'Be default sDelimiter is '/' but it can be specified as something else

    Dim varSection As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Check if strFind exists in strContent by itself with the delimiter
    If InStr(1, sDelimiter & strContent & sDelimiter, sDelimiter & strFind & sDelimiter, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'It exists, loop through delimited sections of strContent to return the position
        For Each varSection In Split(strContent, sDelimiter)
            i = i + 1   'Increase section count
            If varSection = strFind Then    'Check for match
                'Match found, return position and exit for loop
                findPos = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next varSection
    Else
        'No match found, return 0
        findPos = 0
    End If

End Function
```